# How to set Tomcat environment variable to System environment property?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

This is my VM argument from the the tomcat server and i want to set this variable to my system environment. please if any one knows any other option let me know.

```
-Denv.demo.url="tcp://localhost:61616?j=1000"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` system environment (note *environment* not *property*) which is read by all java tools (e.g. java, javac, etc.). You can set this environment variable to contain the option you pass to set the system variable, e.g.:

```
SET JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Denv.demo.url="tcp://localhost:61616?j=1000"
```

You can set this environment variable globally or locally in the script you use to start your application. More about `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/envvars.html)

Another option would be if you can edit the application code is to set the system property during runtime, e.g.

```
System.setProperty("env.demo.url", "tcp://localhost:61616?j=1000");
```

Or if you want this in a config file, store it in a file and read its value from that file and use `System.setProperty()` to set it just as in the previous example.